# Is there an Event which fires when User changes VS TextEditor Options?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, envdte

Our Application needs to know when a User changed something in the TextEditor Options of Visual Studio.

We already found a way to detect if the user closed the "Options" Window (by adding an EventHandler to the "AfterExecuted" Event of the Command "Tools.Options") which works fine for our Application, but we wondered if there is a more granular Event we could use.

Comment: Which options specifically are you looking at? There are different events for different options.

Comment: We are interested in changes to the "Text Editor" Options, specifically to the Options of the Language Option Pages (Basic, C#, C/C++ and so on)

Comment: Is there any specific ones _in_ that? Unfortunately that's not specific enough for general advice... :-(

Comment: Oh, i understand, but I dont think more specific makes sense for us. 

We want to detect changes to  the settings because we want to Backup all TextEditor Settings whenever a change was made by the User.

But, speaking to an expert, i would be interested on which events there are available for a specific option (any of your choosing in the TextEditor Settings). :)
Do you have an example (or a pointer to documentation) for such an Event?